# XSLT: dealing with ignore case and loop

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I have a problem getting values while ignoring case. What happens is that when users enter data about equipment that they use they may enter 38e135 for the equipment number but later in the form they may enter 38E135. When I loop through the equipment ids, I need to treat these as one.

When I try this I get them as two different equipment numbers.

```
<xsl:key name="distinctEquipNum" match="//EquipmentNumber" use="."/>
```

When I try to use the translate function I only get one of them.

```
<xsl:key name="distinctEquipNum" match="//EquipmentNumber" use="translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
```

Here is the loop that I use to get the data

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//EquipmentNumber[generate-id() = generate-id(key('distinctEquipNum', .)[1])]">
        <xsl:variable name="equipNum" select="."></xsl:variable>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="$equipNum"/></td>
```

Is there a way for me to loop through the equipment numbers and ignore case?

Here is a sample of the XML that I am working with,

```
<Timesheet>
    <Equipment>
      <EquipmentWorkOrder>
         <EquipmentWorkOrderNumber>220923134</EquipmentWorkOrderNumber>
<EquipmentDetail>
            <EquipmentMileage>1123</EquipmentMileage>
            <EquipmentHourMeter>Hour Meter</EquipmentHourMeter>
<EquipmentType>Bucket truck</EquipmentType>
            <EquipmentNumber>38e135</EquipmentNumber>
            <MondayHours>6</MondayHours>
            <TuesdayHours>Tuesday</TuesdayHours>
            <WednesdayHours>1</WednesdayHours>
            <ThursdayHours>Thursday</ThursdayHours>
            <FridayHours>Friday</FridayHours>
            <SaturdayHours>Saturday</SaturdayHours>
            <SundayHours>Sunday</SundayHours>
        </EquipmentDetail>
    </EquipmentWorkOrder>
    <EquipmentWorkOrder>
        <EquipmentWorkOrderNumber>220923378</EquipmentWorkOrderNumber>
        <EquipmentDetail>
            <EquipmentMileage>72155</EquipmentMileage>
            <EquipmentHourMeter>Hour Meter</EquipmentHourMeter>
            <EquipmentType>4x4 Pickup</EquipmentType>
            <EquipmentNumber>2a3557</EquipmentNumber>
            <MondayHours>6</MondayHours>
            <TuesdayHours>3</TuesdayHours>
            <WednesdayHours>5</WednesdayHours>
            <ThursdayHours>2</ThursdayHours>
            <FridayHours>Friday</FridayHours>
            <SaturdayHours>2</SaturdayHours>
            <SundayHours>Sunday</SundayHours>
        </EquipmentDetail>
    </EquipmentWorkOrder>
    <EquipmentWorkOrder>
        <EquipmentWorkOrderNumber>220923134</EquipmentWorkOrderNumber>
        <EquipmentDetail>
            <EquipmentMileage>Mileage</EquipmentMileage>
            <EquipmentHourMeter>133</EquipmentHourMeter>
            <EquipmentType>Back Hoe</EquipmentType>
            <EquipmentNumber>122</EquipmentNumber>
            <MondayHours>Monday</MondayHours>
            <TuesdayHours>8</TuesdayHours>
            <WednesdayHours>3</WednesdayHours>
            <ThursdayHours>Thursday</ThursdayHours>
            <FridayHours>Friday</FridayHours>
            <SaturdayHours>Saturday</SaturdayHours>
            <SundayHours>Sunday</SundayHours>
        </EquipmentDetail>
    </EquipmentWorkOrder>
    <EquipmentWorkOrder>
        <EquipmentWorkOrderNumber>220925520</EquipmentWorkOrderNumber>
        <EquipmentDetail>
            <EquipmentMileage>72155</EquipmentMileage>
            <EquipmentHourMeter>Hour Meter</EquipmentHourMeter>
            <EquipmentType>Bucket truck</EquipmentType>
            <EquipmentNumber>38E135</EquipmentNumber>
            <MondayHours>6</MondayHours>
            <TuesdayHours>Tuesday</TuesdayHours>
            <WednesdayHours>1</WednesdayHours>
            <ThursdayHours>Thursday</ThursdayHours>
            <FridayHours>Friday</FridayHours>
            <SaturdayHours>Saturday</SaturdayHours>
            <SundayHours>Sunday</SundayHours>
        </EquipmentDetail>
    </EquipmentWorkOrder>
</Equipment></Timesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to apply the same transformation to the value that you use to *retrieve* from the key as you used when *defining* it, i.e. if the key is

```
<xsl:key name="distinctEquipNum" match="EquipmentNumber"
 use="translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')"/>
```

then the Muenchian grouping expression needs to do the same `translate`

```
<xsl:for-each select=".//EquipmentNumber[generate-id() =
    generate-id(key('distinctEquipNum',
      translate(., 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    )[1])]">
```

(Note that you don't need `//` in the key's `match` expression, just use `match="EquipmentNumber"`)